Redash docker throwing an error called [PID:9][ERROR] Exception on / [GET]
My docker compose:
  redash:
    container_name: example_redash
    image: redash/redash:10.1.0.b50633
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - REDASH_SECRET_KEY=example
      - REDASH_COOKIE_SECRET=example
    ports:
      - 5000:5000

I added redash to my docker-compose file like this. But when I visit localhost:5000, it throws an error.
How can I add redash to my docker-compose.yml file?
Screenshot:

